# Why does light hitting a charged particle cause it to oscillate?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

I am trying to study the **classical** Physics interpretation of light hitting a charged particle.

Why does light hitting a charge particle, such as an electron, cause it to oscillate?

Is it because the light hitting it produce an electromagnetic wave, which causes the particle to vibrate? Are photons moving in space creating electric fields for charges to move, which create a magnetic field, which then repeats the cycle?

Comment: @CosmasZachos it's not a **classical** effect

Comment: @Ruslan I tried to suggest light does all sorts of things to charged particles in actuality.

Comment: Classical light has no photons. Nevertheless the classical electromagnetic wave mathematically emerges from the superposition of zillion of photon quantum mechanical wave functions. To understand the mathematics one  needs to study quantum field theory. See this https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In classical electromagnetism, light **is** an electromagnetic (EM) wave. Photons are quantum objects that are absent in classical physics.

EM-waves are composed of oscillating electric and magnetic fields. Charged particles are sensitive to EM fields, which make them move in a definite direction. Then if the EM fields oscillate, then the particle oscillates as well.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I was too lose with how I defined light.